# How should I intepret より in this sentence

Tags: translation, syntax

```
きのうは　きょうより　ひとが　すくないです。
```

Is it saying:

> X number of people yesterday < Y number of people today?
>
> or
>
> X number of people yesterday > Y number of people today?

I'm getting the translation of より confused and can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: As for yesterday, compared with today, the people are few. (There were fewer people yesterday than there are today.)

Comment: @Billy shouldn't this be an answer?

Comment: Sure, why not...

Comment: I was going to put almost the exact same thing as my answer, but I didn't want to have a duplicate answer/comment.

Comment: Okay. I don't especially mind either way. I've taken your advice and posted my comment as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Where does this sentence come from?  The sentence sounds unnatural to me because of the lack of past form.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto:  But the comparison is being made "now" (`少ない`) and not yesterday (`少なかった`).  Isn't that correct?

Comment: @istrasci: No, although the comparison is made now, the sentence describes how many people there were yesterday, and we use past form because of this.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto:  Yes, I hear it now after saying it several times.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: An example I got from some old study lessons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for yesterday, compared with today, the people are few. (There were fewer people yesterday than there are today.)

Comment: Ah. So it's `X number of people yesterday < Y number of people today`

Comment: Yes. The point is that the noun suffixed by より is a point of reference to measure the rest of the sentence against.